# Application passwords not working on localhost?

Tags: errors, rest-api

I have to get following error on the `localhost`

```
"code":"application_passwords_disabled"
```

[image]

- **Server & Apache:** Xampp v3.2.4
- **OP:** Win 10 64Bit
- **WP:** v5.6.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That error could happen if [`wp_is_application_passwords_available()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_application_passwords_available/) returns a `false`, and the docs says:

> By default, Application Passwords is available to all sites using SSL
> or to local environments. Use
> ‘[wp_is_application_passwords_available](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_is_application_passwords_available/)’
> to adjust its availability.

So, to enable the Application Passwords:

- Enable SSL on your `localhost`,
- Or define `WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE` either as a global system variable or constant, and set its value to `local`:

  ```php
  // Example when defining it as a constant.
  define( 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'local' );
  ```
- Or use the `wp_is_application_passwords_available` hook like so:

  ```php
  add_filter( 'wp_is_application_passwords_available', '__return_true' );
  ```

Comment: Hey, Sally! It took 10 days, but at last, I managed to do what I was going to when we last had a chat. And the system didn't filter it this time. So now I can fully express my thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, thanks a million, @ArsenK.! (but I hoped this and the others have helped or would truly help you )

Comment: They did help! I've learned a lot from your answers. And I was impressed that most of them are really comprehensive. I must say - you are a true WP monster! :)

Comment: Thanks again @ArsenK.! I'm glad my answers helped you :)